# Excel UDF in XLL RTD edit causes formula to lose correct topic

Tags: c++, windows, excel, xll, rtd

I am building XLL + RTD in the same dll. The RTD is not called directly from Excel but through 
wrapper formula. Similar to sample here [Custom Functions in Excel: Part V, XLL-RTDs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430703/Custom-Functions-in-Excel-Part-V-XLL-RTDs)

The functionality seems to be working but when I edit formula inputs manually Excel confuses the edited formula with the one with topic number 0. Both ConnectData for edited item and DisconnectData for old item are called with correct topic ids.

What might be solution for this?

Comment: Could you post your wrapper and some example of the formula and your edits? Excel will call Connect & Disconnect if the RTD function is called with new topic strings.

Comment: It is quite a big project I can not isolate functionality. Both Connect and Disconnect are called with correct values. The issue is that when function is triggered by RTD RefreshData Excel thinks it was called from fifferent location. The one where topicId = 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "Excel thinks it was called from different location"? Excel calls your RTD server's RefreshData function, and you must return the topics to be updated. I'm not sure how you are inferring the 'location that Excel thinks it was called from'.

Comment: I use Excel4( xlfCaller, &xlOut, 0 ) ; return &xlOut;  Somehow when I edit inputs in place Excel will return address of different cell here.

Comment: Is this in your wrapper UDF? Is this perhaps an array formula?

Comment: I found the bug. It was in addTopic processing. Thank you Govert for trying to help. Your library is fantastic I use it a lot.

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad there's not another RTD bug to deal with...